# Why do women in Star Trek usually wear leggings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-uniforms

Why do women in Star Trek (since The Next Generation) almost always wear leggings under dresses and skirts? Reasons women in real life might wear leggings include practical things like fashion, modesty, or warmth -- however the design choice in Star Trek seems very intentional since they're worn even under very long dresses (i.e. when modesty isn't an issue, even by very conservative standards); similarly, leggings are seen across enough different species that it wouldn't seem to be fashion (because it's bizarre that across so many cultural differences, leggings are the only common thread). Is there a known design or production rationale?

Comment: They don't always; https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCKb0.jpg / https://i.imgur.com/cPCqpO3.jpg / http://www.startrek.com/uploads/assets/articles/insettnggirls.jpg

Comment: Maybe space ships have their interior design standards from the 1950's so that they are engineered for the comfort of men in suits. No one temperature is absolutely comfortable for absolutely everybody.

Comment: "In zero gravity, the bolt doesn't hang, if you get my meaning."  Perhaps it's a routine precaution given the fact that artificial gravity may, even if very unlikely, fail.

Comment: Why isn't there a "close because based on false premise" option. :)

Comment: @valorum please excuse my narrowly-inaccurate absolutes -- although you'll note that those examples are from very early in TNG, and the trend is very clearly away from skirts without leggings (same as the trend is very clearly away from men wearing skirts in Starfleet).

Comment: out of universe: because William Ware Theiss stopped working on Star Trek :D

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO - If you do a good image search, I see skirts without leggings pretty consistently from Uhura in TOS to...well...Uhura in Star Trek (2009) reboot. All series, dresses without leggings seem to predominate. Many wear the legged jumpsuit instead of a dress, but that isn't he crux of your question. (Quite a few wear hose, but those aren't leggings and that is common among all women.)

Comment: @Paulie_D - You could always VTC with that as a custom reason. :)

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO - are meaning non-Starfleet costumes? I wonder if the initial assumption of your question by people was taken to mean you were asking about Starfleet uniforms. For example - civilian / humanoid alien clothing (ie - Amanda Rogers in True-Q for example) - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/True_Q_(episode)

Comment: @NKCampbell including civilians -- e.g. in DS9 the Founders and Leeta